# get post id using custom filed value

Tags: custom-field, get-posts

I'm having custom field "prime" with values yes or no. I want to get the post id's with selected value "**Yes**".How can i get that.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this

```
$posts = get_posts( array(
    'numberposts' => -1,
    'meta_key' => 'prime', 
    'meta_value' => 'yes' 
    ) );

$post_ids = array();

if ( $posts ) {
    foreach ( $posts as $post ) {
        // Push post's IDs into array
        array_push( $post_ids, $post->ID );
    }
}
```

code isn't tested but it should work. If you don't wont post ids into array just replace whole `array_push` line with `$post->ID`

**UPDATE**

Set 'numberposts' argument to  -1, so it will return all posts not only 5 as default. Thanks to @Brady

Answer (score 2):

Personally I would use a custom SQL query to do this as then I'm returning just the ID's that I need. But to do it the WP way you can use this:

```
$posts = get_posts(
    array(
        'numberposts'     => -1,
        'meta_key'        => "prime",
        'meta_value'      => "yes",
    )
);
```

$posts will hold an array of objects. These objects hold all the post data you would need for a loop etc